# Partial not rendering in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, erb, partials

Trying to render the following partial: _no_login_required_links.html.erb @ root/index

```
<li id="hobby">
  <%= link_to hobby_posts_path do %>
    <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Find a hobby 
buddy
  <% end %>
</li>

 <li id="study">
   <%= link_to study_posts_path do %>
    <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i> Find a 
study buddy
  <% end %>
</li>

<li id="team">
  <%= link_to team_posts_path do %>
    <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> Find a team member
  <% end %>
</li>
```

So I placed it in another partial called _side_menu

here is _side_menu 's contents

```
<div id="side-menu"  class="col-sm-3">
  <ul id="links-list">
   <%= render 'pages/index/side_menu/no_login_required_links' %>
 </ul>
</div>`
```

for some reason it doesn't render when I go to the homepage, however when I place the partial in this file: _main_content.html.erb , like this 
it renders...

```
<div id="main-content" class="col-sm-9">
  <%= render @posts %>
  <%= render 'pages/index/side_menu/no_login_required_links' %>
</div><!-- main-content -->`
```

here is my index.html.erb file

```
<%= render 'posts/modal' %>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <%= render 'pages/index/side_menu' %>
      <%= render 'pages/index/main_content' %>
  </div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- container -->
```

I do not want to render the side menu in the main contents partial though, any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Looks good. Did you see HTML, that it produces? I see different width: `class="col-sm-3"` and `class="col-sm-9"`. May be that's the reason. It rendered but you don't see it

Comment: _no_login_required is a side nav bar. I normally wouldnt render this in the _main_content partial... I just did this as a test to see if there was something wrong with the _side_menu partial in which I am trying to render _no_login_required in.

Comment: Are `_side_menu` and `_no_login_required_links` in the same folder? If so, maybe your path is wrong.

Comment: `_no_login_required_links` path: views/pages/index/side menu/no_login_required_links ..... `_side_menu` path: views/pages/index/side_menu

Comment: I tried creating a Rails app to demo what you’re describing here and had no trouble.... My app was Rails version 5.2.2 Does your folder structure look something like this? https://gist.github.com/gordonbisnor/0cf5b182577a55f552e9b4a582e69005

It might help to see your routes file, and your controller file... It sounds like Rails thinks your partial is rendering based on the log output...

Comment: Yes that is my exact folder structure.
routes file: https://gist.github.com/KelOkekpe/4f52e247488c7933ed258cc85089d305
It may be important to note that when I remove the HTML from the `_side_menu.html.erb` file, and leave only the `<%= render 'pages/index/side_menu/no_login_required_links' %>` line, the links show. However, I need the HTML for styling purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem...

I had a scss called `mobile.scss` that adjusts the webpage styles according to the screen size of the device it is being viewed on..

In mobile.scss, I had the following styles:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .pc-menu {
    display: none !important;
  }
 }


#side-menu {
     display: none !important;
  }
```

`#side-menu` should have existed within `@media screen and (max-width: 767px)`

since it wasn't, it was hiding the side-menu all together, regardless of screen size.

Placing `#side-menu` within `@media screen` fixed the problem.